# RxJS merge when previous stream receives first value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

**Short explanation of what I want:**

I have an array of observables and I want the results of all of them to come through the same stream. Initially I want the first observable to be activated, and as soon as an observable receives its first value, I want the next observable to be activated.

**Long explanation of what I want:**

The solution I am looking for lies somewhere between the RxJS creation operators “merge” and “concat".

I have an array of observables. Each observable will have several emissions over time. I want to queue these observables after each other so that initially only the first observable is activated *(this is similar to how “concat” works)*.

Then, as soon as the first observable receives its first value I want the second observable to be activated. As soon as the second observable receives its first value I want the third observable to be activated, and so on. *(This is different from “concat”. “concat” waits for the previous observable to be finished, but in my use case I want to wait for the previous observable to have received it’s first value)*

There will be only one resulting stream that emits the values from all the activated observables *(this is similar to how “merge” works)*.

I do not think there is a specific RxJS operator for this, but I hope a solution can be found by mixing multiple operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as soon as the first observable receives its first value

Observables don't receive values, subscribers do; this distinction is important here, because it matters at which point we subscribe to each observable. For example, if we don't think of this in terms of subscribers, then

```
merge(
  a$,
  a$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(b$)),
  b$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(c$)),
)
```

would be a solution – but my assumption here is that this isn't what you meant. It does get us closer to a solution, though. What we'd need instead is this:

```
merge(
  a$,
  a$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(b$)),
  a$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(b$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(c$)))),
  // …
)
```

Of course we need to find a generic solution for this. A naive approach would simply be to "recurse":

```
const activatedMerge = (sources) => {
  const activatedSources = sources.reduce((result, source, idx) => {
    result.push(idx === 0 ? source : result[idx-1].pipe(first(), switchMapTo(source)));
    return result;
  }, []);

  return merge(...activatedSources);
};

activatedMerge([a$, b$, c$]).subscribe(console.log);
```

There might well be a better solution than this, unfortunately I ran out of time. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Concerning the "as soon as the first observable receives its first value", you are right, I described this poorly. Thanks a lot for the answer, I will take a closer look at it and see if I can get it working for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cascade Merge

This should do what you describe, it just recursively merges a new stream each time a first value is seen from the previous stream.

```js
function cascadeMerge<T>(...observables: Observable<T>[]): Observable<T>{
  if(observables.length < 1) return EMPTY;
  return observables[0].pipe(
    mergeMap((v,i) => {
      if(i === 0 && observables.length > 1){
        return concat(
          of(v),
          cascadeMerge(...observables.slice(1))
        )
      }
      return of(v);
    })
  );
}
```

The benefit of this over something like:

```js
merge(
  a$,
  a$.pipe(first(), switchMapTo(b$))
)
```

is that you only `subscribe` to each stream once. You don't have to worry about hot vs cold observables or if you're multicasting.

```js
cascadeMerge(a$, b$, c$).subscribe(console.log);
```